# I want to get size of Javascript object

Tags: javascript

I created an object in JavaScript and stored some information in the object. I searched a lot for solution, but did not find any solution. I want to get the count/length of object.

```
Javascript Code:
productDetail = new Object();
productDetail["Code"] = "A104";
productDetail["ProductName"] = "Keyboard";
productDetail["UnitPrice"] = 10;
productDetail["Dealer"] = "AMD";
```

Comment: What about nested object? What about array inside of that object? Did `Object.keys().length` not work for you?

Comment: Thanks, worked for me. very quick solution.

Comment: Your question starts with: _I have a JavaScript object, is there a built-in or accepted best practice way to get the length of this object?_. The one from 2008 starts with: _I have a JavaScript object, is there a built-in or accepted best practice way to get the length of this object?_. The exact same 111 characters. What are the odds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```
Object.keys(productDetail).length
```

You are after *the count of the property keys of the object*.

```js
const productDetail = new Object();
productDetail["Code"] = "A104";
productDetail["ProductName"] = "Keyboard";
productDetail["UnitPrice"] = 10;
productDetail["Dealer"] = "AMD";

console.log(Object.keys(productDetail).length)
```